# 'Getting i.filter is not a function' in Atom while searching for a package

Tags: installation, package, themes, atom-editor

I am trying to install a package in Atom editor but I am getting the following error message: `Getting i.filter is not a function`.

I tried re-installing Atom but the issue still persists.

[image: Atom - Install Packages - Failed search]

Comment: I know this is no work around, but at least I could find and install packages through the webpage rather than in-app: https://atom.io/packages

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried going to the website and I cannot fetch the package page at all. The packages are pretty basic (git-plus, script). @abhivemp's answer doesn't help either since I cannot load ```atom-live```

Answer (score 5):

Problem with Atom's server, an alternative is to search for the package you're looking for on google in your web browser, then download directly from the atom.io website. This also works.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. And at the same time, searching packages on atom.io website also encountered `HTTP Error 500`. Waiting for 10 minutes, the website service recovered, installing packages in Atom was also back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the `atom-live` package. Go into your settings > package and uninstall then reinstall that package. That should do the job.

Comment: I have this problem too, but I don't have `atom-live` installed in the first place.